# How do I convert a map to a SearchSourceBuilder?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch 2.x, we were using `source(Map)` to initialise a `SearchRequest`'s source:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.source((Map<?,?>) request.get("search_request"));
```

In Elasticsearch 5, all `source(...)` methods are gone, replaced by one taking `SearchSourceBuilder`. That much is documented.

But how on earth do I convert a `Map` to a `SearchSourceBuilder`? There don't seem to be any useful factory methods in there and I have already scoured for other methods taking `Map` and nothing seems to jump out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you highlight [has been reported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6371) but this is not possible anymore [because of this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/13859).

You can read [the full story](https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-great-query-refactoring-thou-shalt-only-parse-once) relating to this big change, but in two words, in ES 2.x the coordinating node (i.e. the one receiving the query) would delegate the parsing of the query to each shard and not only that was a waste of resources (mainly CPU cycles) but there were also a few other drawbacks in that it wasn't possible to optimize the query in a single place.

In ES 5, they decided that the coordinating node would do the parsing ONCE and then send the parsed query to each shard. If you read that blog post I linked to, you'll see that this is supposed to be a big improvement. Of course, that means that you're not able to use the `SearchRequest.source(Map)` method anymore.

**UPDATE**

The [original source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/15a62448343fd24f8e63f43b1e4b16f50005e4a5/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequest.java#L265-L273) of the `source(Map)` method looked like this:

```
public SearchRequest source(Map source) {
    try {
        XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.contentBuilder(Requests.CONTENT_TYPE);
        builder.map(source);
        return source(builder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ElasticsearchGenerationException("Failed to generate [" + source + "]", e);
    }
}
```

Nothing prevents you from having that code for doing the transformation in your application code.

I haven't tested it but then you should be able to create a `SearchSourceBuilder` like this:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

// from Map to XContent
XContentBuilder builder = ... // see above
// from XContent to JSON
String json = new String(builder.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
// use JSON to populate SearchSourceBuilder
JsonXContent parser = createParser(JsonXContent.jsonXContent, json));
sourceBuilder.parseXContent(new QueryParseContext(parser));
```

Comment: I'm fine with switching to source(SearchSourceBuilder)... but all I was given is a Map, so I still somehow have to convert that, don't I? :/

Comment: Did this help ?

Comment: I hope to get time to check this out today. :)

Comment: Ah, right... they removed source(XContentBuilder) too.

Comment: Yes, but that method only just called `XContentBuilder.bytes()` which you can then easily transform to a String

Comment: I don't get it... I'm trying to get to a SearchSourceBuilder. :/ I think what I'm going to do is comment it out and let someone else on the team hit the problem later.

Comment: That wouldn't be very cool for the next colleague... See my updated answer

Comment: With a bit of adjustment (parseXContent takes a lot more params than that but they're all available in the SearchRequestParsers) this works. :)

Comment: @Val This isn't working for me the createParser method being called isn't defined or qualified.  Can you correct?

Comment: @AlanObject Look [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/dbb6fe58faf27598d7bb735365710903c1ef137d/libs/x-content/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/json/JsonXContent.java)

Comment: @Val I think there have been enough changes in the API that I opened a new article to cover it, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453679/converting-a-java-map-to-a-searchsourcebuilder-elasticsearch-java-high-levela-ap). Any help you can provide would be appreciated.