# Converting a Java Map to a SearchSourceBuilder Elasticsearch 7.2 Java High Level API

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I am writing a REST application (javax.ws.rs) that takes search requests from clients and submits them to the Elasticsearch high-level API.  I want the clients
(browser based javascript mostly) to be able to compose their searches using the Elasticsearch REST API instructions.

The REST end point is defined like this:

```
@Path("list")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response list(Map<String, Object> req) {
  ...
```

The following code would implement a security layer function and then pass the query on to **SearchRequest** object pretty much unchanged. So I don't want to build queries using **QueryBuilders** here.

I have tried the instructions in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754860/how-do-i-convert-a-map-to-a-searchsourcebuilder) but it doesn't work.  I think the **createParser** method has changed since that example was written.  If someone could review this and suggest a solution that would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Using ES 7.2 I have come up with the following code.  There have been many changes in the API not all of which I understand but here is what seems like it should work.

```
        XContentBuilder xcb = XContentFactory.contentBuilder(Requests.CONTENT_TYPE);
        xcb.map(req);
        String json = Strings.toString(xcb);

        XContentParser parser = JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(
                NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, LoggingDeprecationHandler.INSTANCE, json);
        SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        ssb.parseXContent(parser);

        SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest(Log.INDEX);
        sr.source(ssb);

        SearchResponse resp = client.search(sr, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I get an IOException off of the call to `parseXContent`.   Looking with the debugger the string `json` has unprintable characters in it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Which version of elastic are you using? Please be specific.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater I updated my article with code and I think I am close.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I found a code pattern that works and it seems a bit convoluted but logical.  There is no documentation anywhere that would lead you to this.  This was pieced together from some fragments posted in message boards here and there.

```
    try {

        // convert the Map into a JSON string to parse.  Alternatively
        // you could just take the string directly from the HTTP request
        // but the Map form makes it easy to manipulate. 

        XContentBuilder xcb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        xcb.map(req);
        String json = Strings.toString(xcb);

        // Create an XContentParser and borrow a NamedXContentRegistry from
        // the SearchModule class.  Without that the parser has no way of
        // knowing the query syntax.

        SearchModule sm = new SearchModule(Settings.EMPTY, false, Collections.emptyList());
        XContentParser parser = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON)
                .createParser(new NamedXContentRegistry(sm.getNamedXContents()),
                              LoggingDeprecationHandler.INSTANCE,
                              json);

        // Finally we can create our SearchSourceBuilder and feed it the
        // parser to ingest the request.  This can throw and IllegalArgumentException
        // if something isn't right with the JSON that we started with.

        SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        ssb.parseXContent(parser);

        // Now create a search request and use it

        SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest(Log.INDEX);
        sr.source(ssb);
        SearchResponse resp = client.search(sr, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I have tested this with a number of different JSON queries from the client and they all seem to work the way the direct REST API would.   Here is an example:

```
{
    from: 0,
    size: 1000,
    query: {
      match_all: { boost: 1 }
    },
    sort: [
      { timestamp: { 'order': 'asc' } }
    ]
}
```

Hopefully this post will save someone else from the painful search I went through.  I would appreciate any comments from anyone who could suggest a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
XContentBuilder xcb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
xcb.map(req);
String json = Strings.toString(xcb);

SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
ssb.query(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(json));
```